# rails param is missing or the value is empty: post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have been stuck on this problem for a while now and have searched through solution after solution and so far, the ones i have come across do not work.

i made a new rails scaffold for a new Object  for my application, i have the table set up and i can view the Post objects when i run the server.

The problem when i go to view the Post objects when my server is running, it's content does not display, and i cannot update the objects this error gets thrown:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: post
```

The `Posts table` in the database looks like this:

[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqD1a.jpg)

As you can see, the field `content` has data that i want to display on my page when i go to view said Post.

This is what comes up instead:

[what i see when running the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spWZD.jpg)

AS you can see, it wont display the content of the `content` field.

This is my `posts_controller.rb`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # you may want to udpate these posts? typo's outdated info?
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update


    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

i thought this would allow me to see the `content`

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end
```

And i thought this is what defines`:post` because of `before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is what is shown on the error page in rails:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"tHFQAWv08aUoi7ndZsVC1aCNJkYP6hE8w+89NTTpBjc=",
 "commit"=>"Update Post",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

I am really confused to why this is happening, im new to rails so no doubt im missing something basic.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: can you put your html code, because that is where I think the problem is

Comment: @OmarMowafi No need now! you mentioning that made me remember i needed to update the html so thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I think you should close the question or update it with what you were missing for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is missing the `post` param:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"tHFQAWv08aUoi7ndZsVC1aCNJkYP6hE8w+89NTTpBjc=",
 "commit"=>"Update Post",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

This is most likely due to an error in the form in your `app/views/posts/edit.html.erb` view. The form should look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @post, url: {action: "edit"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= end %>
```

You can read more about forms in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).